# Discord Bot Not Playing Audio When Using YouTube-dl and FFmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

I'm trying to get a bot to join a voice chat and then play the audio in a youtube url. This is the code I have:

```
@client.command() async def play(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await channel.connect()

    opts = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(opts) as ydl:
        song_info = ydl.extract_info('video', download=False)
        URL = song_info['formats'][0]['url']
    voice_client.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

No errors are thrown but it just says [youtube] video: Downloading webpage

Comment: Does the audio plays and then stops or it will never start at all? Can you enable debug on ffmpeg to see more details? Finally, I would try to list audio formats from youtube-dl and choose another one (instead of best)

Comment: @SuRGeoNix How do I enable debug on ffmpeg? I'm using a venv so I just copied the 3 exes from the bin download into my scripts folder. When I run it, it says downloading but nothing is playing. Do you have any code to use for this because I don't know all the syntax for youtube_dl

Comment: Try reading the documentary, as there might've been something about youtube_dl or ffmpeg you might've missed.